# DAX Calculate measure returning count of "1" when it should be "0"

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table:

| ID | Backlog Period | Backlog Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/11/23 | Old |
| 2 | 03/11/23 | Old |
| 3 | 03/11/23 | Med |
| 4 | 03/11/23 | New |
| 5 | 03/11/23 | New |
| 6 | 04/11/23 | Old |
| 7 | 04/11/23 | Old |
| 8 | 04/11/23 | Old |
| 9 | 04/11/23 | New |
| 10 | 04/11/23 | New |

I created the following Dax function:

```html
IF (
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT('Tickets'[ID]),
        'Tickets'[Backlog Period]=MAX('Tickets'[Backlog Period])
    ) = BLANK (),
    "0",
    CALCULATE(COUNT('Tickets'[ID]),'Tickets'[Backlog Period]=MAX('Tickets'[Backlog Period]))
)
```

To check it, I have created a table visual. It counted "1" for "Med", but it should be "0" as there is no "Med" for the 4th of november, which is the MAX date (MAX('Tickets'[Backlog Period])):

| Backlog Age | Backlog per day |
| --- | --- |
| Med | 1 |
| New | 2 |
| Old | 3 |

What I need is that "Med" displays "0":

| Backlog Age | Backlog per day |
| --- | --- |
| Med | 0 |
| New | 2 |
| Old | 3 |

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Backlog per day = 
  var maxD = CALCULATE( MAX('Tickets'[Backlog Period]), ALLEXCEPT('Tickets', 'Tickets'[Backlog Period]) )
  var result = IF(ISINSCOPE('Tickets'[Backlog Period]),
    COUNT('Tickets'[ID]),
    CALCULATE(COUNT('Tickets'[ID]), 'Tickets'[Backlog Period] = maxD )
  )
  RETURN COALESCE(result, 0)
```

You need the `ALL` to get the max of the whole table. Otherwise this `MAX('Tickets'[Backlog Period])` was getting the max date per `[Backlog Age]`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works. The issue now is that the line chart only shows the latest value as well. In the line chart I would need to show the total backlog (count of ID) for each day (Backlog Period). Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Updated answer above with `IF(ISINSCOPE(Tickets'[Backlog Period]), ....`

Comment: Thank you again, this solved the linechart, now I ran into another issue, sorry. When I now filter to an earlier date, the cards that I have return 0 instead of its value. I think after that all should be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the issue. I've updated the answer above and changed `ALL('Tickets')` to `ALLSELECTED('Tickets')` - see if that is what you are after.

Comment: Hello, sorry. same issue. I use a "Between" Slicer, and when I move the slicer from the extreme right a little bit to the left (changing the end date of the report), my cards display "0".  So the "Backlog per day" returns 0 instead of the actual value. But in the line chart it works. I don't understand.

Comment: Updated answer above to use `ALLEXCEPT('Tickets', 'Tickets'[Backlog Period])`

Comment: Awesome :). Thank you so much for your quick help.